# Adding certain files from a folder

Tags: git

I have a folder `temp/` with ten files, but I need to `git add` only three of them. What is the easiest way to do so besides adding `temp/` and then doing `git reset` for unnecessary files?

```
bash-3.2$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    temp/
```

Comment: Note that you can run `git status -uall` and get a list of each of the files in `temp/` instead of a collective "there are some untracked files in temp/". `-u` can be spelled `--untracked-files=`, if you like the longer name, and the options are `all`, `normal`, and `no`.

Comment: @ torek Thank you! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just list them.
Thanks to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) for reminding us about `-u`

```
$: git status -u
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    x/0
    x/1
    x/2
    x/3
    x/4
    x/5
    x/6
    x/7
    x/8
    x/9


$: git add x/3 x/5 x/7
$: git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   x/3
    new file:   x/5
    new file:   x/7

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    x/0
    x/1
    x/2
    x/4
    x/6
    x/8
    x/9
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I hoped that there is a way to do so without invoking `ls`.

Comment: Note - once you add some of the files in the subdir, you don't need `-u` anymore for other untracked files in the now-tracked dir, though it never hurts.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, I would like to recommend you trying [tig](https://github.com/jonas/tig), On the `status view` of tig, you can easily choose files to be staged.